# How to run LaTeX with `--shell-escape` on sharelatex

Tags: graphics, pdftex, sharelatex, epstopdf

I'm working with ShareLatex and I'm uploading .pdf image, so it takes a long time to compile because it is a large document. I found it is possible to automatic convert .pdf images to .png using:

```
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{epstopdf}
  \epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule{.pdf}{png}{.png}{convert #1 \OutputFile}
  \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.png,.pdf}
```

which will speed up the compiler but it seems that I need to call pdflatex with the `--shell-escape` option. The question is, how is it done in Sharelatex?

Here is the info of the webpage of [ShareLatex](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Inserting_Images)

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried running it? I know it states on https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Inserting_Images#!#Generating_high-res_and_low-res_images that you need to run with `--shell-escape` but you also need this to use the `minted` package. ShareLaTeX does however have `minted` support.

Comment: Yes I had. What outputs it's the document without the image. It doesn't generate the .png image, so I think the compiler just ignore the figure environment

Comment: @ThorbjørnE.K.Christensen You were right. For some reason I just ran it again and worked. Thank you anyway for your help :)